# Add .a static library to IOS plugin

Tags: ios, plugins, tensorflow2.0, podspec

I need to import .a library into ios plugin. On plugin I see we have `.podspec` file but I dont know how to config in `.podspec` file to import .a library

My library is `tflite-dist/libs/ios/libtensorflow-lite.a`

My podspec file

```
require "yaml"
require "ostruct"
project = OpenStruct.new YAML.load_file("../pubspec.yaml")

Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = project.name
  s.version          = project.version
  s.summary          = 'Agora.io offical flutter sdk plugin.'
  s.description      = project.description
  s.homepage         = 'https://github.com/agoraio/flutter-sdk'
  s.license          = { :file => '../LICENSE' }
  s.author           = { 'Agora' => 'developer@agora.io' }
  s.source           = { :path => '.' }
  s.source_files = 'Classes/**/*'
  s.public_header_files = 'Classes/**/*.h'
  s.dependency 'Flutter'

  s.dependency 'AgoraRtcEngine_iOS_Crypto', '2.9.1'
  s.preserve_paths = 'opencv2.framework'
  s.xcconfig = { 'OTHER_LDFLAGS' => '-framework opencv2' }
  s.vendored_frameworks = 'opencv2.framework'
  s.static_framework = true
  s.ios.deployment_target = '8.0'
end
```

My folder has structure like image below

[image]

Comment: I have face same problem. have you find solution?

Comment: I define config on `agora_rtc_engine.podspec` file like 

`s.vendored_libraries = 'libtensorflow-lite.a'`